# Search list and order List by value max found c#

Tags: c#, linq

i like to confess that i am weak in LINQ.
i have list with data. i want to search list fist by given value and then sort data by max occurance means which comes maximum time in rows.

```
        List<SearchResult> list = new List<SearchResult>() { 
            new SearchResult(){ID=1,Title="Cat"},
            new SearchResult(){ID=2,Title="dog"},
            new SearchResult(){ID=3,Title="Tiger"},
            new SearchResult(){ID=4,Title="Cat"},
            new SearchResult(){ID=5,Title="cat"},
            new SearchResult(){ID=6,Title="dog"},
        };
```

if i search & sort list with data like **"dog cat"** then output will be like

```
ID=1,Title=Cat
ID=4,Title=Cat
ID=5,Title=Cat
ID=2,Title=dog
ID=6,Title=dog
```

all cat will come first because this cat keyword found maximum time in all the rows and then dog found maximum time.

this below data will not come because it is not in search term

```
ID=3,Title=Tiger
```

looking for solution. thanks

### UPDATE PORTION CODE

```
        List<SearchResult> list = new List<SearchResult>() { 
            new SearchResult(){ID=1,Title="Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899"},
            new SearchResult(){ID=2,Title="Excavator JCB - ECU P/N: 728/35700"},
            new SearchResult(){ID=3,Title="Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899"},
            new SearchResult(){ID=4,Title="JCB Excavator - ECU P/N: 728/35700"},
            new SearchResult(){ID=5,Title="Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899"},
            new SearchResult(){ID=6,Title="dog"},
        };

        var to_search = new[] { "Geo", "JCB" };
        var result = list.Where(sr => to_search.Any(ts => String.Compare(ts, sr.Title, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0))
                         .GroupBy(sr => sr.Title.ToLower())
                         .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count());

        var matched = result.SelectMany(m => m);

        var completeList = matched.Concat(list.Except(matched));

        dataGridView2.DataSource = completeList.ToList();
```

i try to your logic in another apps but it is not working. according to logic three rows first come with GEO keyword and then next 2 rows comes with JCB and then unmatched rest comes. what i need to change in ur code. please help. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will filter your list and group it by `Title`, sorting the groups by their size.

```
List<SearchResult> list = new List<SearchResult>() { 
    new SearchResult(){ID=1,Title="Cat"},
    new SearchResult(){ID=2,Title="dog"},
    new SearchResult(){ID=3,Title="Tiger"},
    new SearchResult(){ID=4,Title="Cat"},
    new SearchResult(){ID=5,Title="cat"},
    new SearchResult(){ID=6,Title="dog"},
};

var to_search = new[] { "cat", "dog" };

var result = list.Where(sr => to_search.Any(ts => String.Compare(ts, sr.Title, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0))
                 .GroupBy(sr => sr.Title.ToLower())
                 .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count());

foreach (var group in result)
    foreach (var element in group)
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("ID={0},Title={1}", element.ID, element.Title));
```

**Output:**

```
ID=1,Title=Cat
ID=4,Title=Cat
ID=5,Title=cat
ID=2,Title=dog
ID=6,Title=dog
```

If you don't care about the actual grouping, just can flatten the list of groups with [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx).

(Note that this code will ignore the case of `Title`. I don't know if this is what you want or if it is a typo in code: you are using `cat` and `Cat`, and in your output it is only `Cat`, but `dog` is not capitalized.)

**Edit:**

To get the unmatched items, you can use [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx):

```
var unmatched = list.Except(result.SelectMany(m => m)); // beware! contains the tiger!
```

**Edit 2:**

```
var result = list.Where(sr => to_search.Any(ts => String.Compare(ts, sr.Title, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0))
                 .GroupBy(sr => sr.Title.ToLower())
                 .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count());

var matched = result.SelectMany(m => m);

var completeList = matched.Concat(list.Except(matched));

foreach (var element in completeList)
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("ID={0},Title={1}", element.ID, element.Title));
```

**Output**

```
ID=1,Title=Cat
ID=4,Title=Cat
ID=5,Title=cat
ID=2,Title=dog
ID=6,Title=dog
ID=3,Title=Tiger
```

**Edit 3**

```
var result = from searchResult in list
             let key_string = to_search.FirstOrDefault(ts => searchResult.Title.ToLower().Contains(ts.ToLower()))
             group searchResult by key_string into Group
             orderby Group.Count() descending
             select Group;
```

Comment: what trick i need to add in the code if i want unmatched data should come also at end like ID=3,Title=Tiger?

Comment: i want the output should be like 
ID=1,Title=Cat
ID=4,Title=Cat
ID=5,Title=cat
ID=2,Title=dog
ID=6,Title=dog
ID=3,Title=Tiger

all unmatched data come at bottom

Comment: @Thomas See my Edit 2. All elements are put into a single list (called `completeList`). All unmatched elements are at the bottom.

Comment: can u please do me one more favour. suppose i have string variable like string data="JCB Excavator - ECU JCB P/N: 728/35700" in this string i need to find out count or how many "JCB" words are there in string variable "data" by linq. please give me small code with solution. thanks

Comment: @Thomas OK, but please ask a new question for this :-)

Comment: one urgent issue.i try to put your logic in another apps but it is not working. according to logic three rows first come with GEO keyword and then next 2 rows comes with JCB and then unmatched rest comes. what i need to change in ur code. please have look & help. thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13619/discussion-between-bigyellowcactus-and-thomas)

Comment: thanks it works....but another sorting i want that....that GEO rows should come first which row data has the word GEO maximum time. this is my second requirement. will u please do the modification accordingly. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should do the trick.

```
var searchText = "cat dog";
var searchResult = list
  .Select(i => new { 
       Item = i, 
       Count = list.Count(x => string.Compare(x.Title, i.Title, true) == 0)  // Add counter
  })
  .Where(i => searchText.Contains(i.Item.Title))
  .OrderByDescending(i => i.Count)
  .ThenBy(i => i.Item.ID)
  .ToList()
```

**Update**

If you want unmatched data at the end, you need to add another sorting property in the anonymous object.

```
var searchText = "cat dog";
var searchResult = list
  .Select(i => new { 
       Item = i, 
       Matched = searchText.Contains(i.Item.Title.ToUpper()),
       Count = list.Count(x => string.Compare(x.Title, i.Title, true) == 0)  // Add counter
  })
  .OrderByDescending(i => i.Matched)
  .ThenBy(i => i.Count)
  .ThenBy(i => i.Item.ID)
  .ToList()
```

Comment: what trick i need to add in the code if i want unmatched data should come also at end like ID=3,Title=Tiger?

Comment: this line giving error l.Title? where is l?? .ThenBy(i => i.ID)??

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<string> pets = new[] { "Cat", "dog", "Tiger", "Cat", "cat", "dog" };
var test = pets
    .Where(p=>p.ToUpperInvariant() == "CAT" || p.ToUpperInvariant() == "DOG")
    .GroupBy(p => p.ToUpperInvariant())
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .SelectMany(p => p);

foreach (string pet in test)
    Console.WriteLine(pet);
```

Comment: what trick i need to add in the code if i want unmatched data should come also at end like ID=3,Title=Tiger?