# Ordering List data by LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

this way i am trying to order data

```
        List<SearchResult> list = new List<SearchResult>() {
        new SearchResult(){ID=1,Title="Geo Prism 1995 GEO GEO- ABS #16213899"},
        new SearchResult(){ID=2,Title="Geo Prism 1995 GEO - ABS #16213899"},
        new SearchResult(){ID=3,Title="Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899"},
        new SearchResult(){ID=3,Title="Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899"},
        new SearchResult(){ID=4,Title="Wie man BBA reman erreicht"},
        new SearchResult(){ID=5,Title="Ersatz Airbags, Gurtstrammer und Auto Körper Teile "},
        new SearchResult(){ID=6,Title="JCB Excavator - ECU P/N: 728/35700"},
        };

        var to_search = new[] { "Geo", "JCB" };
        var result = from searchResult in list
                     let title = searchResult.Title.ToLower()
                     let key_string = to_search.FirstOrDefault(ts => title.Contains(ts))
                     orderby key_string == null ? -1 : title.Split(new[] { key_string }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length descending
                     group searchResult by key_string into Group
                     orderby Group.Count() descending
                     select Group;

        var matched = result.SelectMany(m => m);
        var completeList = matched.Concat(list.Except(matched));
        dataGridView2.DataSource = completeList.ToList();//.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

data is showing in grid but the way i am expecting data that is not coming.

### output is coming now

```
ID  Title
```

---

```
1   Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899
2   Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899
3   Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899
3   Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899
4   Wie man BBA reman erreicht
5   Ersatz Airbags, Gurtstrammer und Auto Körper Teile 
6   JCB Excavator - ECU P/N: 728/35700
```

### but i want to show data this below way

### output should be like

```
ID  Title
```

---

```
1   Geo Prism 1995 GEO GEO - ABS #16213899
2   Geo Prism 1995 GEO - ABS #16213899
3   Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899
3   Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899
6   JCB Excavator - ECU P/N: 728/35700
4   Wie man BBA reman erreicht
5   Ersatz Airbags, Gurtstrammer und Auto Körper Teile
```

JCB should come after all the GEO because i am sorting data with the search word like
**"geo jcb"** . geo found in title of most of the rows. so those rows come first which has occurance of my search word. so geo is one of my search word and it present maximum time in all rows title. next jcb should come because jcb is in my search term but in output jcb related rows coming at last. so tell me how to change my linq query. thanks

Comment: I'm confused on your goal here.  I originally misunderstood your question, but it looks like you want all items, but you want "matched" items to filter to the top?

Comment: again those rows will come first which will have maximum occurance of word. first sort will be like which search term found maximum time in the rows then those rows will come first. next again sort like which sort term found maximum time in title that will come first. two sorting need to be there.

Comment: yes i want first extarct match item and then sort on match item....after that concatinate sorting data with unmatch item at end.

Comment: I think you have asked this question enough times http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395704/search-list-and-order-list-by-value-max-found-c-sharp
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392014/sort-list-by-occurrence-of-a-word-by-linq-c-sharp/11392150#11392150
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393627/complex-sorting-list-by-occurrence-of-a-word-by-linq-c-sharp

Comment: i am very sorry hogan and i apologize for posting bit similar kind of question in this Q/A. i never work with linq some use very basic purpose but my requirement was very complicated....that why i failed & failed & frustrated. so put this kins of Q/S here. sorry once again and thanks for bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class SearchResult{
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string Title{ get; set; }
}

void Main()
{

    List<SearchResult> list = new List<SearchResult>() {
        new SearchResult(){ID=4,Title="Wie man BBA reman erreicht"},
        new SearchResult(){ID=5,Title="Ersatz Airbags, Gurtstrammer und Auto Körper Teile "},
        new SearchResult(){ID=6,Title="JCB Excavator - ECU P/N: 728/35700"},
        new SearchResult(){ID=2,Title="Geo Prism 1995 GEO - ABS #16213899"},
        new SearchResult(){ID=3,Title="Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899"},
        new SearchResult(){ID=1,Title="Geo Prism 1995 GEO GEO- ABS #16213899"},
    };

    var to_search = new[] { "Geo", "JCB" };

    var result = from sr in list
                 let w = to_search.FirstOrDefault(ts => sr.Title.ToLower().Contains(ts.ToLower()))
                 where w != null
                 let a = new {sr=sr, word=w.ToLower()}
                 group a by a.word into g
                 orderby g.Count() descending
                 let sorted = g.OrderByDescending(a=> a.sr.Title.Select((c, i) => a.sr.Title.Substring(i)).Count(sub => sub.ToLower().StartsWith(a.word)))
                 from a in sorted 
                 select a.sr;

    var completeList = result.Concat(list.Except(result));

    foreach (var element in completeList)
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("ID={0},Title={1}", element.ID, element.Title));
}
```

---

**Output:**

```
ID=1,Title=Geo Prism 1995 GEO GEO- ABS #16213899
ID=2,Title=Geo Prism 1995 GEO - ABS #16213899
ID=3,Title=Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899
ID=6,Title=JCB Excavator - ECU P/N: 728/35700
ID=4,Title=Wie man BBA reman erreicht
ID=5,Title=Ersatz Airbags, Gurtstrammer und Auto Körper Teile
```

Comment: your output looks good. now it is working. i will get back to u after implementing it in my our job if any issue arises.thaks a lot

Comment: i was very happy after executing ur query but i became very disappointed when i execute ur query against huge data then it did not work perfectly. when i search against the keyword like "audi geo" then huge data comes for audi. result was started with audi...it was ok but after audi record result should suppose to start with keyword geo but after audi other records show and then records come with geo & other record too. so i just do not understand why this behave strange when list has huge data. can u put some light if u understand what i am trying to say. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    var result = (from searchResult in list
                 let title = searchResult.Title.ToLower()
                 let key_string = to_search.FirstOrDefault(ts => title.Contains(ts))
                 orderby key_string == null ? -1 : title.Split(new[] { key_string }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length descending
                 group searchResult by key_string into Group
                 select Group).OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count()).ThenByDescending( grp => CountStringOccurrances(grp.Key, to_search));

public static int CountStringOccurrences(string text, string[] pattern)
{
    // Loop through all instances of the string 'text'.
    int count = 0;
    foreach (string itm in pattern)
    { 
       int i = 0;
       while ((i = text.IndexOf(itm, i)) != -1)
       {
          i += itm.Length;
          count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Huh?  He does not want it ordered by title.  Ersatz comes after Geo.

Comment: Fixed with new found reading comprehension/understanding of problem.

Comment: this line giving error. error msg is "group does not exist in current context" OrderByDescending(group => group.Count()).ThenByDescending(CountStringOccurrences(group.Key, to_search));

Comment: Apologies, group is reserved word.  Rename "group" to another name.